# How to have a specific condition inside a super class constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I'm having problems creating an if statement inside a constructor super class because when I create an object of type sub class my year variable initializes to zero. Can someone please help me identify the problem?

```
public abstract class Ship implements Floatable {

private String name;
private int year;

public Ship(String n, int y) {
    if(year > 1950)
        year = y;
    else 
        year = 0;
    name = n;

}
```

//code for sub class

```
public class CruiseShip extends Ship {

private int maxPsg; //max number of passengers
public CruiseShip(String name, int year, int max) {
    super(name, year);
    maxPsg = max;
}
```

Comment: This `if(year > 1950)` should be `if(y > 1950)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here     `if(year > 1950)`, `year`  can only be valued to `0` as it is declared as :

```
private int year; // 0 value by default
```

and you never valued it.

What you want to write is probably :

```
public Ship(String n, int y) {
    if(n > 1950)
        year = y;
    else 
        year = 0;
    name = n;    
}
```

But as `int` fields are by default initialized to `0`, you could so simplify as :

```
public Ship(String n, int y) {
    if(n > 1950)
        year = y;
    name = n;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change `if(year > 1950)` to `if(y > 1950)` otherwise the condition will never become true as `year` is initialized to zero by default due to the fact that it's an instance field.